# Can't change wallpaper on XFCE

Tags: xfce, desktop-background

everyone! I'm running Xubuntu right now but I can't get to change the wallpaper. I've tried through Settings and from right clicking on an image but the wallpaper never changes. If there's any log you need just tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does Right-Click anywhere on the desktop and choosing Desktop Settings allow you to change the Wallpaper?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad english... i use another language in my system...

- Right click on the desktop
- Choose Desktop Settings
- Directory
- other...
  find the path: usr/share/xfce4/backdrops
  You can't open ANY files, BUT sellecting "Open" or "OK", appear ALL!